# LibreOffice Writer - Add footnotes outside of two-column layout?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, footnote

I have a multi-page two-column document as shown 
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwRLj.png) When I add footnotes by using Insert > Footnote, the footnotes end up inside the respective column. Is it possible to create footnotes (not endnotes) at the bottom of each page, spanning both columns? Or, even better, change up settings so whenever I insert a footnote it *automatically* places itself to outside the columns?

I saw a thread on the [help site](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/37481/create-a-footnote-section-with-columns/) for LibreOffice but all it said was to use Insert > Section. My columns are already in sections, and (1) when I add a new section for the footnotes it ends up being at the top of the next page and (2) I can't put stuff under the main two-column section since it spans multiple pages. I would hate to need to break it into a section for each page.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible with LO Writer / OOo Writer currently. There's a ugly [workaround to refrain from using footnotes and use numbering instead, formatting them as footnotes](http://ooo-forums.apache.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=72399)... You may add an [enhancement request to LO bugzilla](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport).

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use a table of two columns and write inside the table. The footnotes will then appear as usual below the paragraph area.

Is this what you want?